# Mimicking windows shortcut to folders for quick desktop access

Tags: nautilus, directory, desktop-environments, shortcuts, navigation

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 within Virtual Box, I'm a bit new to Unix-Linux type OS's. I'm used to Windows and their ability to create shortcuts to objects. Now, I do understand that Linux is not Windows, and that it has no concept of shortcuts. Unix based systems have symlinks or symbolic links which is completely different. I'm not trying to create symlinks between objects here...

Consider the following:

Let's say I have 2 or 3 folders in my `home` directory and I `ls` into it...

```
skilz420@skilz-PC:~$ ls
```

These would be the default or most common folders within a clean installation of Ubuntu...

```
Desktop Downloads Pictures snap Templates
Documents Music Public Videos
```

Now, let's say I create 3 directories at this location

```
mkdir Workspace
mkdir Repos
mkdir Temp
```

Now if I `ls` again, these folders or directories appear. This is on the terminal side of things...

If I open up `Nautilus` or the `folder/file viewer` from the `desktop`... I can navigate to the `Home` directory and see these folders there.

I don't necessarily want to create a `shortcut` or a `symlink` directly...

However, I would like to be able to see these folders *On The Desktop* but still "live" in their current location...

In other words, I would see a folder icon on the desktop with the same name as the three above...

However, I don't want the folders on the desktop to having `PATH=home/skilz420/Desktop/"foldername"`, instead I want the visible folders on the desktop to have `PATH=home/skilz420/"foldername"`.

I want the folders to reside where I create them, but to have quick access to them from the desktop...

Is something like this possible, and if so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnome Shell, which Ubuntu uses by default, actually does not support icons on the desktop. For "quick access", the desktop may not be the ideal place. When you are actually working, the desktop is covered most of the time. Ubuntu nevertheless supports desktop folders, however through a Gnome Shell extension that currently has limitations.

The way to quickly access folders would be through bookmarks in the file manager. You can quickly launch Files using the mouse or the keyboard. Bookmarked folders then are a mouse click away. Alternatively, typing two or three letters of the name will quickly reveal the folder, and then it takes hitting Enter to be in the folder.

That said, it is still possible to implement shortcuts, as opposed to symlinks, on the Ubuntu desktop. Such "launchers" are little text files with the `.desktop` extension. Because no graphical tools are provided anymore to create such launchers, by default, you have to create these manually.

To create a launcher that for example opens your "Documents" folder, create a `desktop` file which you could call, for example, `documents.desktop`, in the text editor. Five lines are sufficient to have a working launcher. Enter the following in your text editor:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Documents folder
Exec=xdg-open /home/<youruserlogin>/Documents/
Type=Application
Icon=org.gnome.Nautilus
```

Replace  by your actual login name. Save the file as `documents.desktop` and put it on your desktop. The first time, you will need to right-click the file and give permission to execute it. Only then will the file appear as a regular and functional launcher icon on the desktop.

In this example, the icon is that of Files. You can replace org.gnome.Nautilus by a pathname to any graphical file in .PNG or .SVG format to use the latter as icon.

Most elegant is to collect your custom icons in a folder `.local/share/icons` under your home folder. `.local` is a hidden folder. You will only see it in Files if you turn on "Show hidden files" (hamburger menu, or simply hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to toggle between showing and hiding hidden files. In local, you will find the folder `share`. In the folder `share`, you probably will need to create the `icons` folder yourself because it is not there by default. When you refer to graphics inside that folder, you can just put the file name in your `.desktop` launcher. For example, if you have your custom icon `~/.local/share/icons/documentsfolder.png`, then simply specify the icon as:

```
Icon=documentsfolder
```

You only need to provide a full path if your icon is in a non standard location as in

```
Icon=/home/<yourlogin>/Documents/Icons/documentsfolder.png
```

If you find this cumbersome, and working with "shortcuts" on the desktop is crucial for your workflow, you may want to consider switching to another Linux desktop environment that still fully support this feature. Examples are Mate or XFCE, but also the Plasma desktop, although the latter, being based on a different toolkit (QT), has a different look and feel. Still, it is a look and feel that may be more familiar to ex Window users than the look and feel of GTK based desktops.

Could be a bit overwhelming for a new user, but then, Linux is about choice.

Comment: Very nice and thorough explanation, crisp and clear. Tips, tricks and answers like this, help a lot and they can go a long way. For me, I'm just experimenting with Linux in order to learn Bash and the Unix - POSIX environment. I'm 100% self-taught in programming in C++ and for the longest time I've done mostly Windows type programming with 3D Graphics both Direct X and OpenGL over the years and recently I've been picking up Vulkan and around the same time I started to learn Python. Then I got into Hardware Emulation such as the 6502, MIPS, z80, etc. for I already knew Intel - x86 Assembly...

Comment: Then I got to the point where I knew the software side of things, and wanted to know more about the hardware side of things which lead me to Ben Eater's YouTube series with his 8-bit bread board CPU. I learned a lot from them. I even implemented his design in Logisim on Windows. That was a challenge because Logisim doesn't allow for a pin to be both input and output, so making the Bus connections to all components was not easy. I even made a few modifications within the ALU. Instead of a basic ripple carry adder, I implemented a Look Ahead Adder. ...

Comment: I then wrote a C++ app similar to his C app to generated the binaries needed for the CPU's control logic ROMs. I also built the 4 x 7-Segment Display in Logisim too. All of my components were made with Gates... I didn't use any "built-in" features. I was able to run his Assembly and was able to generate the same output! This helped to teach me more about where the Software meets the Hardware! I've always had the background in both Mathematics and Physics and could write high level programs with very limited assembly. This lead me into wanting to learn other fields...

Comment: So I started to dive into Compiler Design and Operating System Design. When I got into writing boot loaders and kernels... it came to the point where Linux was sort of needed since I'm writing them within the `EFI` framework and had to work with ELF files. Since I'm not running Windows 10 I can not use `WSL`. I have to run a Linux Distro in Virtual Box to use `CGG` to generate the needed `ELF` files for `EFI` to make my boot-loaders and kernels, and this is where I'm not at...

Comment: Now, I do find it amusing that Linux users assume that people who are coming from Windows for some reason or another is an "ex-Windows" user... My primary OS is still Windows... Windows 7 to be exact. I'm just using - experimenting with different Linux Distros through Virtual Box to get a feel for how Bash works in comparison to Window's Command Prompt. The file and folder system is completely different, and the simlinks, forks and piping is something that Windows doesn't have... however, Windows does have shortcuts and a registry...

Comment: I can't say if I like Windows or Linux better than the other. They both have their purposes, their strengths and their weaknesses. For me, I'm just an enthusiast about Computers in General, except for when it comes to Mac-Apple, I'll turn them into v-sauce! I don't mind Linux for I do support Open Source, however if I have to use Proprietary I'll still go with Microsoft before I would with Apple! One of the main reasons is when it comes to Gaming, I know the Windows System better to configure it to my liking. I've been at it since Dos 6.0 - Windows 3.1 & Doom!

Comment: This type of shortcut does directs you to the exact folder location. Symbolic links does not do that. Very helpful. Thanks.